# Disabling auto-translation from English to another language?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've installed Drupal 8 and setted the site to be in Hebrew. It was changed to Hebrew, but from some reason, all the management system area\navigation\menues themselves were also translated to Hebrew. Such a thing never happened to me In Drupal 7.

In Drupal 7 when I was installing sites and setting the language to Hebrew, I would only have everything moving to the right (Hebrew is an RTL language) and the usage in the language became available, but I never, ever, had all the site translated automatically.

Is there a way to allow Hebrew **without** translating every part of the site to Hebrew?

[image]

Comment: There is no need to put _Drupal 8_ in the title. This site is about Drupal, and we have a tag for Drupal 8, [tag:8], which is always visible where the question is visible.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't using https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_language on your Drupal 7 site for force the Admin to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve it:

1. I've deleted the Hebrew language setting to re-create it later.
2. I've **un-installed** the module "Configuration translation" and than the module "Interface translation".
3. I Re added the Hebrew language as supported, and setted it as default.

Now the site was supporting Hebrew but no longer translated everything to it automatically.

Comment: This only works, until you update the Hebrew language. That is loading the .po-file for that language to `/sites/default/files/translations/` automatically or manually. If you want to remove the translation again, you don't have to uninstall the modules, you can simply remove the .po-file of one language.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question fully, you can do this, use the Hebrew language without the two modules, this will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the administration language seperate to the content language by setting:

```
/admin/config/regional/language/detection:
Account administration pages: enabled
```

If you want to force this, set this setting at the top of the list.

Then there is in the user configuration of admin's the option to set a different language for the site and the administration pages language.

For other roles, just set the permission "Use the administration pages and help" to allow this setting to appear on the user page.

Comment: The problem with that approach is interface parts that are used outside the administration pages (for example admin toolbar) still gets translated which is very annoying. Benia's answer prevents that.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose a language at Drupal 8 install, then the interface will be translated by default. Useful for users who do not speak English. The translations are automatically imported from localize.drupal.org.

If you do not want the interface to be translated just uninstall the "Interface translation" module.

If you want Interface translation, but do not want to import translations from localize.drupal.org, then restrict the Translation source.
Translation files with translated interface text are imported automatically when languages are added or when modules or themes are enabled. On the "Interface translation settings" page (/admin/config/regional/translate/settings), the "Translation source" can be restricted to local files only.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove the second language (in my case Turkish). Then I added a custom language with code for example "mytr". The only downside is your translated pages are now accessible from www.example/com/mytr/... instead of www.example.com/tr/...